# Techniques for handling arrays whose storage requirements exceed RAM

Tags: matrix, fortran, libraries

I am author of a scientific application that performs calculations on a gridded basis (think finite difference grid computation). Each grid cell is represented by a data object that holds values of state variables and cell-specific constants. Until now, all grid cell objects have been present in RAM at all times during the simulation.

I am running into situations where the people using my code wish to run it with more grid cells than they have available RAM. I am thinking about reworking my code so that information on only a subset of cells is held in RAM at any given time. Unfortunately the grids (or matrices if you prefer) are *not* sparse, which eliminates a whole class of possible solutions.

**Question:** I assume that there are libraries out in the wild designed to facilitate this type of data access (i.e. retrieve constants and variables, update variables, store for future reference, wipe memory, move on...) After several hours of searching Google and Stack Overflow, I have found relatively few libraries of this sort.

I am aware of a few options, such as this one from the HSL mathematical library: http://www.hsl.rl.ac.uk/specs/hsl_of01.pdf. I'd prefer to work with something that is open source and is written in Fortran or C. (my code is mostly Fortran 95/2003, with a little C and Python thrown in for good measure!)

I'd appreciate any suggestions regarding available libraries or advice on how to reformulate my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this belongs on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Most operating systems automatically provide memory beyond RAM via virtual memory.  It is a frequent problem with Fortran programs that the default stack size is too small.  You can solve this by adjusting an OS setting, using allocatable variables (which typically won't be on the stack) or compiler options for array memory location.  Perhaps one of these ideas will help...

Comment: This probably isn't what you want to hear, but it seems to me if you're doing finite difference with arrays that bit, it's probably time to parallelize your code -- MPI works nicely and it pretty standard.  Of course, that doesn't really help your colleagues who don't have enough memory, since they probably also don't have a computer cluster sitting around...

Comment: You might also dig into out-of-core concepts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-core_algorithm, I guess there are quite some publications on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Bite the bullet and roll your own?

I deal with too-large data all the time, such as 30,000+ data series of half-hourly data that span decades. Because of the regularity of the data (daylight savings changeovers a problem though) it proved quite straightforward to devise a scheme involving a random-access disc file and procedures ReadDay and WriteDay that use a series number, and a day number, with further details because series start and stop at different dates. Thus, a day's data in an array might be Array(Run,DayNum) but now is ReturnCode =  ReadDay(Run,DayNum,Array) and so forth, the codes indicating presence/absence of that day's data, etc. The key is that a day's data is a convenient size, and a regular (almost) size, and although my prog. allocates a buffer of one record per series, it runs in ~100MB of memory rather than GB.

Because your array is non-sparse, it is regular. Granted that a grid cell's data are of fixed size, you could devise a random-access disc file with each record holding one cell, or, perhaps a row's worth of cells (or a column's worth of cells) or some worthwhile blob size. I choose to have 4,096 bytes/record as that is the disc file allocation size. Let the computer's operating system and disc storage controller do whatever buffering to real memory they feel up to. Typical execution is restricted to the speed of data transfer however, unless the local data's computation is heavy. Thus, I get cpu use of a few percent until data requests start being satisfied from buffers.

Because fortran uses the same syntax for functions as for arrays (unlike say Pascal), instead of declaring DIMENSION ARRAY(Big,Big) you would remove that and devise FUNCTION ARRAY(i,j), and all read references in your source file stay as they are. Alas, in the absence of a "palindromic" function declaration, assignments of values to your array will have to be done with a different syntax and you devise a subroutine or similar. Possibly a scratchpad array could be collated, worked upon with convenient syntax, and then written back if changed.